# history.js - IE popup Error

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, history.js

I have an example here: http://www.salesmelbourne.com

if you click the page1,page2 etc you can see an IE error.

Any advice on what this is and how I fix it?

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When changing page, the popup appears to be from this piece of code:

```
History.log('statechange:', State.data, State.title, State.url);
```

Which from a quick glance logs to console in browsers with support, otherwise will alert (hence why you get an alert message in IE).

---

You are also getting an alert from **including history.js twice**.

```
scripts/bundled/html4+html5/jquery.history.js
scripts/uncompressed/history.adapter.jquery.js
```

In the plugin, it has the following code to check:

```
// Check Existence
if ( typeof History.Adapter !== 'undefined' ) {
    throw new Error('History.js Adapter has already been loaded...');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's actually a fallback if no console window is available

File: jquery.history.js  (uncompressed)

```
            212 // No Textarea, No Console
        213 else if ( !consoleExists ) {
        214 alert(message);
        215 }
```

I commented out line 214 to avoid the popup!

If you use the bundled compressed html4+html5/jquery.history.js  (vers.v1.7.1-r2.) you might search for the word "alert" and replace the part l=a.alert, with l=a.function(){} to avoid the popup